# I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 box with IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

In Event viewer i have found this:
The World Wide Web Publishing Service service entered the stopped state.
- 
- 
   
  7036 
  0 
  4 
  0 
  0 
  0x8080000000000000 
   
  6913 
   
   
  System 
  w2k8x64 
   
  
- 
  World Wide Web Publishing Service 
  stopped 
  570033005300560043002F0031000000

How to determine, was server stopped by clicking "Stop" in IIS manager or it stopped itself because of some other reasons? When the stop event occured I was logged in via RDP but I don't remember and clicks in IIS Manager...:( there are no error messages in event viewer

Comment: Can you paste the exact Event?

Answer (score 1):

This was likely you stopped it - The w3wp.exe will crash instead of the web service when things go wrong (almost always) - a new worker process (w3wp.exe) will start automatically (with some limits on rapid failures).